# Forge API response limit: Why?

Tags: rest, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to get the list of all projects on my BIM 360 account by using Forge data management API.(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/)

However, when I request it by using GET method, it only gives me 154 elements at maximum. Is it an inherent rate limiting from REST api? Or is it something restricted from Forge?

Advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: That documentation indicates there are `page[number]` and `page[limit]` parameters, which imply some sort of pagination occurs.

Comment: ^ Yes, that's what I also suspected, but apparently changing those parameters doesn't really make a difference in the response...

Comment: How many projects are u expecting ? Can u check if you are indeed assigned to all of them because if not these projects will no show up in the response if you use 3 legged authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As @ceejayoz mentioned, `page[number]` and `page[limit]` are the correct query params you should use to control the pagination behavior. If settings those parameters doesn't have any effect and you're still getting 154 results, please share an example of the REST call here, or share it with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` and we will investigate it further.